# Depending objects, consider rotation when translating an object

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, raphael

I built a simple 2D-car consisting of three elements, using [Raphael JS](http://raphaeljs.com/). For that I have the body as an Image and two tires. I separated the elements because I want the tires to spin in an animation.

```
var curCar = raphael.image("car.png", /* x */ 0, /* y */ 0, /* width */ 120, /* height*/ 82)
var tires = raphael.set();
tires.push(
    raphael.image("tire.png", 2, 50, 32, 32),
    raphael.image("tire.png", 84, 50, 32, 32)
);
```

As you can see, the tires are positioned on the "bottom" of the car and are already aligned right.
Now, curCar follows a path using Raphael.animate, which works fine. For every update of the animation I translate the tires to curCar's position. It kinda looks like this:

```
function animationUpdate (pos) {
    curCar.transform("t" + [pos.x, pos.y] +" r"+ pos.alpha);
    tires.transform("t" + [pos.x, pos.y ]);
};
```

"t" stands for translate(x,y), r stands for rotation. These values are calculated automatically by Raphael.
When following a straight path this all works out, but as soon as curCar is rotating, the calculation for the tires fails.

An example:

curCar is at position x: 100 / y: 200 and is rotated by 10°.
The tires are translated to x:102 / y:150 and x: 184 / y: 250. Thus curCar is rotated by 10° the tires are out of place.

My main question is:

**How do I calculate the correct X/Y-position considering the rotation?
There must be a common mathematical formula doing this.**

Comment: screw and scale are both "s" wired code!

Comment: it might be a little weird, but doing a transformation is pretty easy using the Element.transform(tStr) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The car wheels should be transformed w.r.t. center of rotation of car (body). It is to be noted that the center of rotation can be anywhere w.r.t. the car. For the sake of simplicity, the following code assumes the center of rotation to coincide with the car center.

Finally, Raphael can take care of the mathematical transformations, if translations and rotations are in right the order of execution.

```
var paper = Raphael.paper(0, 0, 500, 400);
    // tire width
var tw = 10,
    thw = tw * 0.5,
    // car width
    cw = 100,
    chw = cw * 0.5,
    // car height
    ch = 50,
    chh = ch * 0.5,
    // x of tire 1 w.r.t. car
    t1xc = -chw - thw,
    // x of tire 2 w.r.t. car
    t2xc = -chw - thw,
    // y of tire 1 w.r.t. car
    t1yc = -chh - thw,
    // y of tire 2 w.r.t. car
    t2yc = chh - thw;

var car = paper.rect(20, 20, cw, ch),
    // car center
    cx = car.attr('x') + chw,
    cy = car.attr('y') + chh,
    // tire 1
    t1 = paper.rect(cx + t1xc, cy + t1yc, tw, tw),
    // tire 2
    t2 = paper.rect(cx + t2xc, cy + t2yc, tw, tw);
// Translate by 100, 100 and rotate by 30 deg
car.transform("...t100,100r30");
// car center post transformation
cx = car.attr('x') + chw;
cy = car.attr('y') + chh;
// Transform tires, with rotation w.r.t. car center 
/* Edited - To add wheel rotation about axle (25 deg) */
t1.transform("...t100,100r30," + [cx, cy] + "r25");
t2.transform("...t100,100r30," + [cx, cy] + "r25");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your code, it's acutally working.
however, how can I still animate the tires if a rotation is already applied for positioning?

Comment: @DavidSkx, I am a bit unsure of the requirement.The animationUpdate function in your code can be changed to accept 3 important params, viz. changeInX, changeInY and changeInAngle. Using the the params with the implementation code from my code will make the car along with the wheels to animate as required.

Or do you want to rotate the wheels about its axle?

Comment: @DavidSkx You may add for yet another rotational factor, this time about object center as the center of rotation. See the added part "r25", which actually rotates the wheel about its own center by 25 deg. This has nothing to do about positioning.

t1.transform("...t100,100r30," + [cx, cy] + "r25");

Comment: @DavidSkx Happy to see the power of Raphael API here. :)

Comment: t1.transform("...t100,100r30," + [cx, cy] + "r25"); is working well. I never knew that you can apply multiple rotations. just awesome. raphael is definately something for animated stuff in modern browsers. i got it to work in IE8 although the animations are really choppy.

Answer (score 1):

Let's leave the translation of the whole car out for the moment. You want to rotate the car and its tires. For each tire, you can find its new center by applying the rotation matrix to its old center.

```
x' = x∙cos α − y∙sin α
y' = x∙sin α + y∙cos α
```

I assume that Raphaël uses the upper left corner as the position of an image. If so, then your original centers would be (2+32/2, 50+32/2)=(18,66) and (84+32/2, 50+32/2)=(100,66). So these would be `(x, y)` for the above formula. The resulting position would be again a center position, so you'd have to subtract 16 from all coordinates. The translation of the whole car could simply be added to that result.

Comment: thx for your reply! i applied that formula in an example you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/QB9C3/
Raphael always uses the middle of the object as rotation point.
when testing, it outputs me weird negative numbers.

Comment: @DavidSkx: Seems Raphaël uses degrees for angles, whereas the standard JavaScript math expects radians. So simply write `alpha*Math.PI/180` instead.